# Disabling a touchpad in Windows

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I want to permanently disable a touchpad in Windows running on my laptop, since firstly, I use a mouse, and secondly, when I work, I often touch it accidentally what causes definite inconviniences.

I tried the following approaches to disable it but with no result:

1. Turned it off through BIOS — there's no such function there;
2. Turned it off through the touchpad configuration utility — there's no such function there;
3. Turned it off through the device manager — the disable button is inactive;
4. Turned it off through a hotkey (*<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>* in my case) — the hotkey doesn't work;
5. Uninstalled the proprietary driver — Windows automatically downloaded the standard driver;
6. Uninstalled the standard driver and turned off the automatic driver download function (*<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>* → "**systempropertiesadvanced**" → **Hardware** → **Device Installation Settings**)  — all the same, Windows downloaded and installed the driver.

How can I disable a touchpad?

Windows 7; the Alps touchpad.

Comment: What laptop brand and model?

Comment: [Sony Vaio E-series](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VPCEJ1M1R_B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly then I disabled this on my friends laptop using the following :

> **1:** Go to the start menu and type in `VAIO CONTROL CENTRE`
>
> **2:** Now click the icon to open the `VAIO CONTROL CENTRE`.
>
> **3:** When you're in the Vaio Control Centre you see option `MOUSE AND KEYBOARD`, which will open up submenu and you will then click
>   `Pointing Device`.
>
> **4:** When you click this you will be given an option to unchecked **Enable Pointing Device**

Comment: @Sharmaoke Did this seriously work? You said you removed the proprietary software. I even included a link to do this in my answer once you installed said software.

Comment: **@ekaj** Yes, it [did](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20481401/vcc.png). The thing was I didn't have VCC installed on my PC. After I did this, I got the ability to turn off the touchpad using the utility. Moreover, now I also can use the hotkey. I didn't quite understand your answer since you say about Synaptics software but I have the Alps touchpad. Also, the second link in your answer is protected. For me it say "403 Permission Denied".

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [this driver](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VPCEJ1M1R_B/downloads/ALDOTH_00244626_0042_5711), and then using the Synaptics software to disable the touchpad.

Once installed, you should be able to do something like [this](http://geekdrop.com/content/how-to-disable-the-touch-pad-on-sony-vaio-and-of-course-enable-it-again).